# C++, Check if Instance comes before Another in memory?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, memory, dereference

I have 2 pointers to nodes in C++:

```
MallocMetadata *first_node, MallocMetadata *second_node
```

How can I check if the first_node comes first in memory before second_node (Both in heap and by first I mean lower address).

1. Is it true to use: `if(first_node < second_node)` ?
2. Let's suppose I want to check if first_node's place in memory is a multiplication of 8 how to do this:

I tried:

```
assert(first_node%8 ==0);
```

But, doesn't compile and I get:

> Invalid operands to binary expression ('MallocMetadata *' and 'int')

Comment: Comparison other than == or != on pointers is only legal if both come from the same array (globally, locally or dynamically allocated), otherwise it is undefined behaviour. You can, though, cast your pointers to `uintptr_t` before comparison or other arithmetic operations.

Comment: @Aconcagua so can you show me how to fix 1? I allocated the MallocMetadata on heap using sbrk() and mmap()

Comment: Are you writing your own malloc implementation?

Comment: You can use [`std::less`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less). It provides a strict total order for any pointer type.

Comment: @Aconcagua -- there are two problems with `uintptr_t`. First, it's optional. Second, it does not make any guarantees about ordering; the only requirement is that when you convert a `void*` to a `uintptr_t` and convert the result back to a `void*` you'll get the original value.

Comment: @PeteBecker But if you convert and an convert back that means at the same time that now two different pointers can be mapped to the same value. So you define ordering on pointers by the order of uintptr_t (optional remains a problem, though), still need to admit the std::less solution appears superior to me. The modulo operation is not yet covered, though.

Comment: @Aconcagua -- yes, you can get an imposed order with `unitptr_t`. But that's not usually what you want for a memory manager; you need to know whether two blocks can be merged, and to determine that you need to know which address actually comes first, and whether there's extra space between the two blocks. `std::less` doesn't quite give you this, either; it provides an implementation-defined ordering. I'd expect it to use logical addresses, but you'd have to check the documentation. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **reinterpret_cast** for converting your pointer to `std::intptr_t` or `std::uintptr_t`, and then do whatever you want with it, for example:

```
if(first_node_intptr < second_node_intptr) {...}
// or
if(first_node_intptr % 8 == 0) {...}
```

But you should remember that:

> If the types std::intptr_t and std::uintptr_t exist, they are guaranteed to be long enough to hold a void* (and hence any pointer to object type). However, they are not guaranteed to be long enough to hold a function pointer.

[Conversion between pointer and integer](https://riptutorial.com/cplusplus/example/13555/conversion-between-pointer-and-integer)

*You should also be aware of the disadvantages of this approach, which @PeteBecker pointed out below.*

Comment: `uintptr_t` is optional, so it might not exist. Worse, there is no requirement that the order of the values you get when you convert two pointers has any relationship to the order of the pointers. The **only** requirement on `uintptr_t` (other than it being an unsigned integer type) is that if you convert a `void*` to a `uintptr_t` and convert the result back to a `void*` you'll get the original value.

Comment: @PeteBecker You might be technically correct, but I doubt any of that will be an issue in practice.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat -- there is a completely portable solution to this problem (`std::less`), so there is no sound reason to apply a faith-based <g> solution. Especially not one based on the glib assertion that you can "do whatever you want with it".

Comment: Memory management is inherently non-portable because it relies on hardware details that are not explicitly part of the C++ memory model. Getting it right requires knowledge of the target hardware and knowledge of what the compiler in fact does. If you don't pay meticulous attention to details you'll end up with code that fails in mysterious and nearly unreproducible ways.

Comment: @PeteBecker you are absolutely right, but... There is no point in thinking about it. There is a concept of "good enough" solution. The only question is which solution is more suitable for the person who asked the question. Very often, a "perfect" solution may not make sense. Post your answer and let Mick choose more appropriate one

Comment: @SageCat -- "good enough" isn't good enough for critical application code. Memory management affects every part of your program, and if you get it wrong you've got something that will often be an undebuggable mess.

Comment: @PeteBecker If this is some kind of test project, the essence of which lies simply in training, then I see no reason to soar over the search for more "correct" solutions. All you need to do is just remember where exactly something could go wrong, why and what to do to avoid this in some important project.

Comment: @SageCat -- sure, you can play around with stuff like this, and maybe get something that limps along. Your answer doesn't say that. It says you "can do whatever you want with it", without qualification. If your goal is to create something that seems to work, by all means do so, but when you recommend an approach like that to someone else, you are, at a minimum, obliged to point out the limitations of the approach. If you don't, how will your innocent victim "remember where exactly something could go wrong"?

Comment: @PeteBecker this is due to the fact that I was not aware of such a flaw in my approach. I'm not a god) All I can do is to hope that the person will not disdain the comments and will find out such a truth. Also, I'll make an appendix